# TabItem Clicked

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, mvvm-light

I have a problem, I have a wpf form with a tabcontrol, inside the tabcontrol there are multiple tabitems. By the way i'm doing the mvvm design patten with mvvmlight. Ok, now I want to pass some data  from the viewmodel that is bound to the first tabitem to the other the second viewmodel that is bound to the second tabitem but only when the second tabitem is clicked. Thanks in advance

Comment: Usually, you'd share data change as it happens rather than when the user interacts elsewhere. Why would that not work for you?

Comment: Yes you are right, and that is what I am doing at the moment with MVVMLight's Messenger. But with MVVM Light's Messenger it takes about 30 seconds if not more for the background work to complete and that makes the whole app slow and frustrating for the end user. This app is complicated, there are 16 or 18 viewmodels and they all interrelated, each 1 handles a small part of data which when displayed all together pains the whole picture to the user. And I am trying to get rid of that 30 second delay by firing the next tabitem to be filled out only when the user clicks that tab.

Comment: Sounds like this 30 second process should be on a background thread. Decoupled from these viewmodels.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a really odd requirement, please correct me if I'm wrong but I suspect that the way you've worded it isn't actually what you're trying to accomplish. The usual way to manage tabs with MVVM is to start by creating a view model for your tab panels:

```
public class TabItemViewModel
{
    public string Header { get; set; }

    // fields for the actual panel items go here

    public override string ToString() => this.Header;
}
```

Then back in your view model you create an observable collection of these and a property to track which tab is currently selected:

```
    public ObservableCollection<TabItemViewModel> MyItems { get; } = new ObservableCollection<TabItemViewModel>
    {
        new TabItemViewModel { Header = "Tab Page 1" },
        new TabItemViewModel { Header = "Tab Page 2" },
        new TabItemViewModel { Header = "Tab Page 3" }
    };

    private TabItemViewModel _CurrentTab;
    public TabItemViewModel CurrentTab
    {
        get { return this._CurrentTab; }
        set
        {
            if (this._CurrentTab != value)
            {
                this._CurrentTab = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.CurrentTab);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your XAML then binds to the collection and the property:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentTab}" />
```

Result:

[image]

Since `CurrentTab` tracks the currently selected tab your view model code can easily check at any time to see if that's the one that the user has currently selected, so there's no need to mess around with the bindings themselves. Since the binding is two-way the view model can also control which tab is currently active, which is particularly handy when adding navigational helpers to your app.

If you genuinely want to remove bindings then it's easy enough to add an extra data field to your view model and then set/clear it in the `CurrentTab` setter.